# Qt and JavaScript mapping data

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

What is the correct way to map Qt data types in JavaScript. I pass a Qt object to JavaScript that I load in the QWebView control. It's not a problem to call an object method from JavaScript if there's no parameters buf if a method has parameters the code doesn't work. For example I have the structure Location:

```
struct Location
{
    QString country;
    QString city;
};
```

I have the method:

```
void UpdateLocation(const Location& location);
```

How to call this method from JavaScript?

Comment: I guess the problem is that javascript is not aware of the `Location`-struct. You could write a function like `void UpdateLocation(QString country,QString city)` and see if that call works. Or make `Location` an `QObject` instead of a `struct`, that should also work.

Answer (score 0):

> How to call this method from JavaScript?

Location should inherit from QObject

struct Location : pubilc QObject {
      Q_OBJECT